# AWS Cloudwatch can not publish to SNS Topic with SSE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a Route53 health check, which submits its metrics into Cloudwatch, and finally Cloudwatch specifies thresholds and should send alerts through SNS.

However, I would like my SNS Topic to be encrypted. When I turn on SNS Topic encryption using the `alias/aws/sns` key I receive these messages in the Cloudwatch message history:

```
{
  "actionState": "Failed",
  "stateUpdateTimestamp": 123456778899,
  "notificationResource": "arn:aws:sns:xx-region-y:zzzzzzzzzz:topic_name",
  "publishedMessage": null,
  "error": "null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ccccccccccccccccccc)"
}
```

This *appears* to not be an IAM issue with Cloudwatch, but with SNS itself being unauthorized to use the KMS resources.

I enjoy using the IAM Policy Simulator for IAM users to identify where their permissions are lacking, but there doesn't seem to be a way to validate a Service's access to other services. Is that a thing I can manage?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html

---

I have also tried this with a CMK with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "route53.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm pretty much throwing darts at a wall with the principals, but I think there's validation for `sns.amazonaws.com`for SNS and `events.amazonaws.com` for Cloudwatch.

I received the exact same error, `"null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ccccccccccccccccccc)"`, when using a CMK in this manner as well. I can understand my CMK not working properly, but the Amazon managed key I think should just work out of the box.

---

I've tried using a CMK which grants `sns.amazonaws.com` and `events.amazonaws.com` with `kms:*` permissions. Same error.

Comment: Have you used cloud trail to view the request that's failing?  I'm not entirely sure it would be logged.  I'm curious because though the doc _I_ linked mentions Decrypt and GenerateDataKey I wonder whether that's sufficient permissions

Comment: Cloudtrail doesn't log the requests :( I can only see the log from Cloudwatch which doesn't include the API call itself. I think perhaps you could be correct. about the permissions. I'll `*` it up.

Comment: @Breedly I'm curious to understand how you found the logs you showed above. I am having similar issues, but I don't know where to find these logs.

Comment: @GabrielC You can see it from the CloudWatch Alarm in the History tab. All events are recorded, you can just click on the event you're interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: It's likely this information is out of date. Please try the other answers and let everyone know if they work for you.

---

Apparently, CloudWatch *can't* send messages to encrypted SNS topics according to [*Protecting Amazon SNS Data Using Server-Side Encryption (SSE) and AWS KMS*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-server-side-encryption.html):

> Currently, CloudWatch alarms don't work with Amazon SNS encrypted topics. For information about publishing alarms to unencrypted topics, see Using Amazon CloudWatch Alarms in the Amazon CloudWatch User Guide.

However, the blog post [*Encrypting messages published to Amazon SNS with AWS KMS*](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/) seems to indicate you can...

Answer (score 10):

Just summarizing the correct answer here because the accepted answer seems to be outdated:.

1. You cannot use the Amazon managed CMK `alias/aws/sns` because in order to connect cloudwatch with an SNS topic encrypted with a KMS CMK, you need to set a resource-policy/access-policy on the CMK so that cloudwatch service can perform `kms:GenerateDataKey*` and `kms:Decrypt` actions on the key and the access-policy on amazon managed keys cannot be edited.
2. For your case, you would need to create a customer managed symmetric CMK, and edit the access-policy to allow cloudwatch service principal to access that CMK. The access-policy will look like:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-policies",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions for administration of this key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow cloudwatch metric to use this key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you have links to documentation or a blog post updating the situation?

Comment: Not a blog post updating the situation but I was able to find this article highlighting the cases in which cloudwatch to sns will and won't work. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-receive-sns-for-alarm-trigger/

Comment: OK, I don't have the need to test this out, but I'll leave a comment on mine to try it out. If people validate yours then I'll swap 'em.

Comment: Was also pulling my hair why this was not working. You just need to add cloudwatch service to your KMS CMK policy

Answer (score 4):

Adding just the below `events.amazon.com` permissions to the KMS key's resource policy did the trick for me, specifically to allow `AWS::Events::Rule` that had encrypted SNS topics registered as `Targets` for 'FAILED' CodeBuild and CodePipeline states.

```
       {
            "Sid": "Allow Events use of key (for publishing to CMK encrypted SNS topics)",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

Hope this saves someone else some of the frustration and time this had caused me.

Answer (score 2):

The service is not "events.amazonaws.com", it is "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com". You should get the SNS notifications once you change this in the key policy.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-server-side-encryption.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

While some AWS services use an IAM Role in your account, others use a specific *principal* to be granted access instead.  See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/.

I think in your case you need to allow the cloudwatch principal, `events.amazonaws.com`, to be allowed to use the KMS key you specified, in the key's policy.   See the section "Enabling compatibility between encrypted topics and event sources" in the above link.

Note that as the document says, "Several AWS services publish events to Amazon SNS topics. To allow these event sources to work with encrypted topics, you must first create a customer-managed CMK and then add the following statement to the policy of the CMK."  This only works with customer managed keys.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to add that info! There doesn't seem to be a way to modify the `alias/aws/sns` KMS key's policy. Key policies seem to only be available to Customer Managed Keys.

I was trying earlier with a CMK whose policy included the principals and actions listed in that blog article.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today! I see there are suggestions for granting the CMK to `cloudwatch.amazonaws.com` and also to `events.amazonaws.com`. For me, I needed to grant to both for that to work. Here is the entirety of my Cloudformation definition for the CMK.

```
 InternalSNSKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Description: IA-Internal-SNS Encryption Key
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: allow-root-access-to-key
        Statement:
          - Sid: allow-root-to-delegate-actions
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
            Action:
              - kms:*
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: allow-cloudwatch-to-use-key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - kms:Decrypt
              - kms:GenerateDataKey*
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: allow-events-to-use-key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - kms:Decrypt
              - kms:GenerateDataKey*
            Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Why is it Resource: * here? Shouldn't it be better to use the ARN of the key, to tighten up security?

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido apenas criando a Key police no KMS re vinculando essa key a SNS que está encrypt;

```
enter code here{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "key-policies",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions for administration of this key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow cloudwatch metric to use this key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```